# Обработка исключений в Spring Boot

Tags: java, исключения, spring-boot

Имеется база mysql/postgres. Нет никакого серверного приложения. В качестве сервера OpenServer. Не используются web-запросы. Запросы к базе только через JpaRepository. Настройка подключения к бд указана в файле application.properties

```
spring.main.banner-mode = off

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/analiz?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Как обработать исключения, возникающие в случае неверно указанного пароля или url подключения?

Comment: Никак - у вас приложение не запустится.

Comment: Никак не получится показать подсказку, что неверные настройки бд?

Comment: А кому вы ее хотите показать? Spring при запуске в log пишет.

Comment: Пользователю. Допустим, есть готовый скомпилированный jar-файл. Если в файле application.properties изменить настройки, то приложение не запустится. В таком случае, хотел показать окно с информацией пользователю.

Comment: Ну если у вас пользователь запускает сервер, сам меняет конфиги, то подскажите ему в каких логах смотреть ошибки запуска.